# Why doesn't Prolog find a solution for 'Fox, goose and bag of beans puzzle' and shows 'true' instead?

Tags: prolog, river-crossing-puzzle

I wanted to solve the "[Fox, goose and bag of beans puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle)" with Prolog as an exercise.

So I wrote

```
p(left).
p(right).
valid((Man, Goose, Fox, Beans)) :- p(Man),p(Goose),p(Fox),p(Beans), Man == Goose.
valid((Man, Goose, Fox, Beans)) :- p(Man),p(Goose),p(Fox),p(Beans), Man == Beans, Goose \= Fox.
valid((Man, Goose, Fox, Beans)) :- p(Man),p(Goose),p(Fox),p(Beans), Man == Fox, Goose \= Beans.

step((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans), "Man", (Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans)) :- 
    valid((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans)), valid((Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans)),
    Man1 \= Man2.

step((Man1, Goose1, Fox, Beans), "Goose", (Man2, Goose2, Fox, Beans)) :- 
    valid((Man1, Goose1, Fox, Beans)), valid((Man2, Goose2, Fox, Beans)),
    Man1 \= Man2, Goose1 \= Goose2.

step((Man1, Goose, Fox1, Beans), "Fox", (Man2, Goose, Fox2, Beans)) :- 
    valid((Man1, Goose, Fox1, Beans)), valid((Man2, Goose, Fox2, Beans)),
    Man1 \= Man2, Fox1 \= Fox2.

step((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans1), "Beans", (Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans1)) :- 
    valid((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans1)), valid((Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans2)),
    Man1 \= Man2, Beans1 \= Beans2.

reachable(S, _,[], S).
reachable(S, Visited, [Step|Steps], Z) :- 
    step(S,Step,Tmp),valid(Tmp), not(member(Tmp,Visited)),
    reachable(Tmp, [Tmp|Visited], Steps, Z).

start((left,left,left,left)).
goal((right,right,right,right)).

solve(Steps) :- start(S), goal(Z), reachable(S, [], Steps, Z).
```

### Question

I thought with `solve(X).` I would get a sequence of valid steps. But instead, I get

```
?- solve(X).
false.
```

Why don't I get a list of steps that go from start to goal?

### Code explained

`valid` checks for a 4-tuple, where the first element is the position of "Man", the second is the position of "Goose", the third is the position of "Beans" if nobody gets eaten.

`step(Situation1, Description, Situation2)` makes a step from a valid situaiton to another valid situation.

`reachable(Start, SituationList, Steps, Goal)` checks if the situation `Goal` can be reached from the situation `Goal` while every situation in `SituationList` gets visited exactly once and `Steps` is a description what steps were taken in which order.

Comment: Did you try to trace execution (using the goal `trace, solve(X)`) to check where your code is failing?

Comment: @PauloMoura I didn't know this. But I've just tried it and the output is quite long and I don't understand everything. For example, what does `p(right) ? creep` mean? Can I suppress those?

Comment: `creep` just means it queried `p(right)` and it "creeps" along to the next goal (one goal at a time). If you keep taking such steps, it should take you goal by goal through your code and you can check that each goal makes sense.

Comment: @mbratch: Thanks, that was it! Currently, swipl shows me a list of ASCII values instead of a string. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use atoms instead of strings: `'Man'` instead of `"Man"` etc. "Strings" in double quotes in Prolog represent the ASCII sequence (list) of character codes.

Comment: Great! If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue causing the failure is a typo:

```
step((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans1), "Beans", (Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans1)) :-
```

Should be:

```
step((Man1, Goose, Fox, Beans1), 'Beans', (Man2, Goose, Fox, Beans2)) :-
```

This will generate correct solutions. There are a few other clean up points:

- You are using double quotes on strings, which in Prolog, is actually a sequence of ASCII codes (prolog List). If you want a string displayed as just a string, you would use Prolog atoms which are enclosed in single quotes. So, for example, `'Man'` instead of `"Man"`.
- The goal of `valid(Tmp)` in your `reachable/2` clause is superfluous since the prior goal of `step` ensures that `Tmp` will be valid according to the `valid` rule.
- In this specific application, the first of two `valid` goals in each `step/3` clause isn't necessary since your first argument comes from a previously validated step. (It depends upon how "general" you want `step/3` to behave).

Beyond that, the `solve/1` still produces many duplicate results, but they are all correct and all the correct solutions are discovered.

Comment: To get all possible solutions only once I think I can use `bagof(X, solve(T), L).` where `T` will be a solution, can't I? (I have no idea what `X` and `L` are good for)